# JQuery radio button filters not working

Tags: jquery, json, radio-button

I am doing a very simple filter using radio buttons, I have three radio buttons in a group. I want to append different data in unordered list(UL) based on the radio button selection.I am using three buttons to filter between veg,non-veg and both(none).The code that I am using

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".getmenu").click(function(){
   $.getJSON("data.json",function(result){
   $.each(result, function(i, field){
    var cat=field.category;
    var t=field.type;

//putting case
          //radio filter one
    if($('.veg').checked) {
    if(t=="veg"){
    switch(cat){
    case "Soups":
    $(".soup").append(field.menu_item + "<br />");
    break;
    case "Main Course":
    $(".main").append(field.menu_item + "<br />");
    break;
    case "Starters":
    $(".starter").append(field.menu_item + "<br />");
    break;
    }
    }
    }
        ////radio filter two
    else if($('.nveg').checked){
    if(t=="non-veg"){
    switch(cat){
    case "Soups":
    $(".soup").append(field.menu_item + "<br />");
    break;
    case "Main Course":
    $(".main").append(field.menu_item + "<br />");
    break;
    case "Starters":
    $(".starter").append(field.menu_item + "<br />");
    break;
    }
    }
    }

       //radio filter three
    else {

    switch(cat){
    case "Soups":
    $(".soup").append(field.menu_item + "<br />");
    break;
    case "Main Course":
    $(".main").append(field.menu_item + "<br />");
    break;
    case "Starters":
    $(".starter").append(field.menu_item + "<br />");
    break;
    }
    }
    }
```

And if am not putting this filter I am able to append the data from json. My file looks like this:

```
   [
   {"category":"Soups","menu_item":"Tomato Soup","type":"veg"},
   {"category":"Starters","menu_item":"Summer Salad","type":"veg"},
   {"category":"Main Course","menu_item":"Black Beans Chicken","type":"non-veg"},
   {"category":"Soups","menu_item":"Lentil Soup","type":"veg"}
   ]
```

Comment: what does your HTML look like? can you provide a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Checking of radio inputs should be `if ($('.veg').is(':checked') {...}`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$('.nveg').is(":checked")
```

Answer (score 1):

I also agree that `.checked` does not work here. I tried plugging that in on jsfiddle and `.is(":checked") works while`.checked` does not.

Here is a working example.

http://jsfiddle.net/earlonrails/W6ZS2/17/

After the checked is fixed your new problem might be that all the json parts are still printed by the else clause no matter which radio button is selected. I am not sure how your page is setup but might want to fixed that part with additional condition checks.

Here is my version of your code. I was just assuming the json was retrieved already.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".getmenu").click(function() {
    result =  [
     {"category":"Soups","menu_item":"Tomato Soup","type":"veg"},
     {"category":"Starters","menu_item":"Summer Salad","type":"veg"},
     {"category":"Main Course","menu_item":"Black Beans Chicken","type":"non-veg"},
     {"category":"Soups","menu_item":"Lentil Soup","type":"veg"}
   ];
    // $.getJSON("data.json", function(result) {
      $.each(result, function(i, field) {
        console.log("got here, each");
        var cat = field.category;
        var t = field.type;

        //putting case
        //radio filter one
        if ($('.veg').is(':checked') && t == "veg") {
          console.log("got here, veg");
          switch (cat) {
            case "Soups":
             $(".soup").append(field.menu_item + "<br />");
             break;
            case "Main Course":
             $(".main").append(field.menu_item + "<br />");
             break;
            case "Starters":
             $(".starter").append(field.menu_item + "<br />");
             break;
          }
        ////radio filter two
        } else if ($('.nveg').is(':checked') && t == "non-veg") {
          console.log("got here, nveg");
          switch (cat) {
            case "Soups":
              $(".soup").append(field.menu_item + "<br />");
              break;
            case "Main Course":
              $(".main").append(field.menu_item + "<br />");
              break;
            case "Starters":
              $(".starter").append(field.menu_item + "<br />");
              break;
          }
        ////radio filter three
        } else {
          console.log("got here, other");
          switch (cat) {
            case "Soups":
              $(".soup").append(field.menu_item + "<br />");
              break;
            case "Main Course":
              $(".main").append(field.menu_item + "<br />");
              break;
            case "Starters":
              $(".starter").append(field.menu_item + "<br />");
              break;
          }
        }
      });
  });
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Optimized code

Instead of doing for every if else go for this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".getmenu").click(function() {
    result =  [
     {"category":"Soups","menu_item":"Tomato Soup","type":"veg"},
     {"category":"Starters","menu_item":"Summer Salad","type":"veg"},
     {"category":"Main Course","menu_item":"Black Beans Chicken","type":"non-veg"},
     {"category":"Soups","menu_item":"Lentil Soup","type":"veg"}
   ];
      $.each(result, function(i, field) {
        var cat = field.category;
        var t = field.type;
          var map = {
              "Soups" : ".soup",
              "Main Course" : ".main",
              "Starters" : ".starter"
          };
          var elementToAppend = map[cat];
          $(elementToAppend).append(field.menu_item+"<br />");
      });
  });
});
```

here is fiddle for this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fZ5Fh/)

You can append with category too. with another map -- `$(type).find(elementToAppend).append(...)`